# How to Reference JavaScript Libraries From Sub-Grid Ribbon Xml

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

We've been using [this described method of accessing common or shared JavaScript libraries from JavaScript actions defined in the ribbon XML](http://blog.allegient.com/blog/dustin-warners-blog/dynamic-javascript-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011).  Ribbon Button --> JS function in Dynamic Library file --> JS function in Library file defined on the form of the entity, and it's been working great.

Today, I attempted to follow the same pattern from a sub-grid ribbon for a different entity (Add JS Library that will be called by ribbon to Form for Entity A.  From form on Entity A, click the Entity Bs link on the left to display related Entity B's Sub-Grid Ribbon XML for Entity B.  Click Button on Sub-Grid ribbon -->  JS function in Dynamic Library file --> JS function in Library file.) but a got an error "Undefined" when attempting to call the JS library referenced by the Entity A form.

It looks like according to [this article](http://madcomputerist.blogspot.com/2012/06/referencing-multiple-javascript.html), I have to either add the appropriate libraries to my Sub-Grid Ribbon XML, or load the web resource dynamically.

Is there an easier way?  Why does referencing the javascript on the form work for the default ribbon xml, but not the sub-grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does referencing the javascript on the form work for the default
>   ribbon xml, but not the sub-grid?

Since the script is loaded with Entity A's Form, it is unlikely that it will still be available when Entity B's subgrid has loaded and replaced the Form.

Adding a reference to the javascript webrsource in the Actions section under the CommandDefinition tag is the supported way of doing what you are trying to achieve. This will load the script when the SubGrid ribbon loads.

The Location attribute in the Custom Action tag will determine when the script will be loaded

Eg:
Location="Mscrm.**SubGrid**.{entity name}.WhereEver

Location="Mscrm.**Form**.{entity name}.WhereEver

Also, since adding breakpoints to the script file will not work for dynamically loaded scripts, add a debug statement to the code instead to invoke the debugger if required.

Comment: So basically, clicking on the Entity B's link on the left will replace Entity A's form and the javascript that has been loaded by it?

Comment: As a clarification, breakpoints in dynamically loaded scripts do work, the problem is since they're dynamically loaded, you don't get an option to set the break point until after it has already ran it's on load script (unless you can find the dynamically loaded script, and set the breakpoint before it executes, which isn't likely).  For our main form ribbon xml javascript, it immediately calls a javascript file defined on the form, and you can put a breakpoint in that file for testing without a debug statement.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the Javascript from Entity A is no longer available once Entity B's subgrid is loaded. Not exactly sure how this mechanism is implemented.. If the javascript was referenced by the document within the contentIFrame, I could understand why it was not available. But it looks like something else is unloading the dynamically loaded scripts. Possibly something within the ribbon rendering scripts.